# ember-cli ember build generates incomplete index.html?

Tags: asp.net, node.js, ember.js, ember-cli, handlebars.js

I am trying to build an ember app with ember-cli. I created the app with `ember new HelloWorld` and built it with `ember build`. Inside the "dist"-Folder is a index.html with this Markup:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <title>HelloWorld</title>
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <base href="/" />
      <meta name="hello-world/config/environment" content="..." />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/hello-world.css">    
    </head>
    <body>
      <script src="assets/vendor.js"></script>
      <script src="assets/hello-world.js"></script>    
    </body>
  </html>
```

In older Ember-Versions we wrote our templates inside this index.html. I know ember "precompiles" the templates now, but where are they? When I open the index.html with a Browser I get an empty page. How does this work now? Do we need to run a node server for the ember-app? I just want to copy the output of `ember build` inside a Asp.Net project and include the files into my index.cshtml.

Answer (score 0):

> In older Ember-Versions we wrote our templates inside this index.html.
>   I know ember "precompiles" the templates now, but where are they?

`index.html` is located in `app/index.html`. Rest of templates is in `app/templates/`.

> When I open the index.html with a Browser I get an empty page. How
>   does this work now?

You should get errors in your console:

```
file:///assets/vendor.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///assets/appName.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///assets/vendor.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///assets/appName.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

It's because you don't have any server which would serve this assets. Opening `dist/index.html` directly via browser will not succeed. You need to setup simple Python server or copy assets to correct directories in your ASP.NET application. It should correctly expose assets paths for your Ember application.

> I just want to copy the output of ember build inside a Asp.Net project
>   and include the files into my index.cshtml.

Do it. Place assets in correct folders, copy `index.html` contents to your `.cshtml` file.

However, I guess your approach won't work. If you want to integrate ASP.NET application with Ember, mixing files etc. you should include Ember library by yourself in ASP.NET files, then write code using globals(`App.IndexController` etc.).

Comment: thank you, I will try that. I have successfully integrated the described approach at the end of your post with older ember-versions. But now I have to "precompile" stuff and I want to integrate this by a VisualStudio taskrunnerjob.

Comment: unfortunately I didn't get any step closer to my goals. I have copied the "compiled" assets folder into the app folder. the app\index.html references the assets inside this path. When I open app\index.html with a browser, the handlebars-stuff "{{content-for 'head'}} {{content-for 'head-footer'}} {{content-for 'body'}} {{content-for 'body-footer'}}" is all I see. Why do I need a Server? This is supposed to be a JavaScript-Framework only. I don't want to run Node or Python or anything else. It's frustrating and I start to regret the decision for Ember...